# openCV detect shapes inside contour

Tags: opencv

Is there a way to detect shapes inside a contour ? On the image you can see give way and no passage signs(triangle on top of circle). Is there a way to detect the circle from this contour? Triangle is easy because of the inner triangle but I cant figure out how to get the circle.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Hough Circle Transform.

It is used to detect circles.

Relevant link: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html